# query to update some complex document like a matrix in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Some document has the following schema:

```
{
  doc: {
    matrix: [
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
     [{..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..},],
    ]
  }
}
```

Can I remove the column with the `index = 2` from `doc.matrix` by using only one query?

I have a solution of this task that uses `N` queries (where `N` = count of *rows* in the *matrix*). But this solution is not optimum..

Perhaps you can suggest another schema to solve this task.

Suggestions like 'use a SQL database' will be ignored :)

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "not optimum" mean?  It runs too slowly?

Comment: yes, exactly. The number N can be very large..

Comment: This would be a trivial operation in a SQL database.

Comment: You are right! But the question is about NoSQL MongoDB

Comment: What you really want is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243 to be implemented

Comment: The problem with suggesting another schema is that your question does not actually explain what you are doing this for. And that would be what was needed in order to give a suggestion. But as presented I don't see any other solution that to simply just show how this is done in a single update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess what you are referring to is the second "column" as opposed to the "row". Considering the following form which is a little better for illustration:

```js
{
    "matrix": [
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
    ]
}
```

So the one query form is really:

```js
db.matrix.update(
    {},
    {
        "$pull": {
            "matrix.0": 2,
            "matrix.1": 2,
            "matrix.2": 2,
            "matrix.3": 2,
            "matrix.4": 2,
            "matrix.5": 2,
            "matrix.6": 2,
            "matrix.7": 2,
            "matrix.8": 2,
            "matrix.9": 2,
        }
    }
)
```

Which is presumably something like what you refer to doing in "N" statments but this just does it on one:

```js
{
    "matrix" : [ 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
        [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] 
    ] 
}
```

So of course your whole "index of" preposition defines that you have some way to identify which element that actually is within the sub-document, but the basic premise stays the same.

So it generally is up to you have such identifiers in your sub-documents, or in a wider sense, something along these lines:

```js
{
    "matrix": [
        [
            { "index": 0, "ident": "A" },
            { "index": 1, "ident": "B" },
            { "index": 2, "ident": "C" }
        ],
        [
            { "index": 0, "ident": "A" },
            { "index": 1, "ident": "B" },
            { "index": 2, "ident": "C" }
        ]

    ]
}
```

And the statement:

```js
db.matrix.update(
    {},
    {
        "$pull": {
            "matrix.0": { "index": 1 },
            "matrix.1": { "index": 1 },
        }
    }
)
```

With this as the result:

```js
{
    "matrix" : [
        [
            { "index" : 0, "ident" : "A" },
            { "index" : 2, "ident" : "C" }
        ],
        [
            { "index" : 0, "ident" : "A" },
            { "index" : 2, "ident" : "C" }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Very good and simple solution. Thanks! But this works only if N is known.

Comment: @Roman Of course, and your question shows that you know it. There is presently no way to actually refer to a value of another field within an update statement for MongoDB. So either if you stored the dimensions in other fields or were able to determine them dynamically (which you can't really, except using aggregate ) then your are still using two queries. But that is better than the "N" queries you were doing. It is arguable that doing two queries you could just manipulate the array in code and then save it back. But this could well be better. A better solution does not exist.